# Wait for multiple Observables in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular5, observable

I'm new in Angular and TypeScript, so question could sound wrong.
I'm using Visual Studio Code and Angular 5 (ng-version="5.2.11").

I need to "await" till my call to api will end and return it's result without wrapping everything in giant ".subscribe".
What I have:

```
exampleMethod(): SettingsClass {
const myComplexObject: SettingsClass = {
  field1: predefined.field1,
  field2: predefined.field2,
  field3: isComplexCalculationsNecessary ? this.CallApi_1(predefined.paramForField3) : predefined.field3,
};

return myComplexObject;
}
```

Previously I had all parameters in "*predefined*", but now I need to query one(or more) from external source, and immediately return "myComplexObject" from method (to some other api call, or other component, or even interface, but I need this object fully defined, with all parameters set). I could turn my code "upside-down" and put everything inside big ".subscribe", but I dont't, because at some point I will need other parameter to query as well, and all this will break. 
How to write call to api, to avoid rewriting all my code each time I need to add new external call? Something like:

```
CallApi_1(paramForField3: string): Observable<int> {
return this.http.get(`${httpConfig.route}?$apply=filter${paramForField3}/groupby${httpConfig.groupingParam}`);
}
```

OR maybe

```
CallApi_1(paramForField3: string): Observable<int> {
return this.ExternalCallsService.GetParam3Information(paramForField3).subscribe(res => 
.GetParam3Information contains the same http call as above, but I need to do
something to return this result outside, I don't know what);
}
```

What I'm looking for is some king of:

```
field3: isComplexCalculationsNecessary ? **await** this.CallApi(predefined.paramForField3) : predefined.field3,
```

I'm currently trying 'rxjs' that have interesting options to work with Observables, like 'forkJoin', but I'm not sure that I'm looking in the right direction entirely, maybe such a trick impossible, or my understanding of Observables is not right and I need to move complex logic to back-end? Please, advise.

Important to notice again, that simple ".subscribe" is not what I'm looking for, because in all subscribe-examples we are not returning values, but assigning it to some global variable or directly to html-element and it's NOT what I need, I need to get value and continue working with it as fast as external resource will return it.

Comment: i think `switchmap` is what you want

Comment: hmm, switchmap's description looks promising, I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rxjs/concat`, take a look on this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-functions-in-sequence?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It would be something like this first, second and so on are functions that returns Observables

```
let sequence = concat([
      this.first, 
      this.second, 
      this.afterSecond, 
      this.third]);

    sequence.subscribe(currentFunction => {
      currentFunction().subscribe(value => {
        this.values.push(value);
      })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I could be wrong, but "this.values" looks like standard global variable, that couldn't be returned, only assigned at some point(and if I will assign it too early, I will get null or undefined, and actual result will be lost). But I will tyr the example you gave.

Comment: this.value is created at the component level and updated in NgOnInit for this example :) a real implementation would have a function that returns an Observable of the values type ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip or forkjoin operators ( they are similar but not the same ) or you can chain your http calls :

```
this.http.get1( url1, headers ).subscribe(
   data => {
      this.data1 = data;
      this.http.get2( url2, headers ).subscribe(
         data => {
            this.data2 = data;
         },
         error2{
            // do something on error2
         }
      )
   },
   error1 => {
      // do something on error1
   }
)
```

This is not very nice but works ok. I remember using zip for solving the same problem.

Edit : I found the zip example

```
     const  tpcomprob$ = this.data.getTPComprob( this.tpcomprobsId);
     const  comprobs$ = this.data.getComprobs(this.tpcomprobsId); 

     this.sbsComprobs = zip(tpcomprob$, comprobs$, (tpcomprob: any, comprobs: any) => ({tpcomprob, comprobs}))
                       .subscribe(pair => {
                          this.tpcomprob = pair.tpcomprob;
                          this.comprobs = pair.comprobs;

        },
        error => {this.httpError = error ;})
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and this probably working. But "this.tpcomprob" and "this.comprobs" are both global variables, that will be assigned at some point in time. I could be sure that they will be assigned simultaneously, but not that they will be assigned at all, so when I'll try to use them - they still could, or could not be empty, without any way to ensure (or force my code to **wait** external requests to be completed). Probably my understanding of asynchronous operations, that I have from .net, is not suits here. I will return to this thread after some investigations.

Comment: From what I see here http://rxmarbles.com/#zip zip will wait till 2 observables complete and emit or error. So both tpcomprob and comprob will be defined.

Comment: Look at http://rxmarbles.com/#concat for this case, concat will also work, as httpClient.get will emit and finish, but I think conceptually it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**forkJoin** is the easiest.

```js
var _arr = [];

_arr.push(this.mySvc.callback01());
_arr.push(this.mySvc.callback02());

forkJoin(_arr).subscribe(resList=>{
    //-- the response will be in array
});
```